# plot elliptic curve over finite field using sage

Tags: plot, sage, elliptic-curve

I want to plot an elliptic curve over a finite field using sage mathematical interface with the following commands:

```
p=2^255-19;
F=Finite Field(p);
C=Elliptic Curve(F,[0,486662,0,1,0]);
plot(C, aspect_ratio = 1);
```

However due to the size of the curve this generates the error:

```
'OverflowError: range() result has too many items'.
```

How can i resolve this problem, or is there any other method to plot this curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about this result:

```
sage: len(C.points())
<same error>
```

Your elliptic curve just has too many points for Python to deal with, much less to plot.  What I would suggest is to start by getting a few points and then using the group law to generate a sample of points and plot that.  I don't know if you'll be able to do that with "out of the box" behavior or if you'll have to imitate the code in `sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.py in _points_via_group_structure(self)` as in the traceback.  Good luck!